# Access table data to be used for labels on lines plotted in a \foreach loop

Tags: pgfplots, plot, pgfplotstable, for-loop, def

I have a large table which contains multiple sets of (x,y) data, and following each such dataset is a constant number, which we can call "C". To save time I want to utilize a `\foreach` loop for the plotting. My issue is that I want to label each of the plotted lines with their corresponding "C"-value. My approach has been to use `\pgfplotstablegetelem` command to get the "C" and assign `\pgfplotsretval` to a command which I then print for the nodes that will generate the labels.

See MWE below. In the code I plot the datasets (A,B), (A,B'), and (A,B'') (and in my real case, this goes on much further). I then desire to print C, C' and C'' for the data set to which they belong. The data is plotted just as intended, but LaTeX runs into an error:

> Undefined control sequence. ^^I^^I\end{axis} and produces the attached
> plot.

How can I have the "C"-values printed on the curves, i.e. 0.1 on the blue curve, 0.25 on the red curve and 0.33 on the brown curve in this example.

(I have also included the result obtained when typing "Preview" for the node text.)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
A,B,C,B',C',B'',C''
1,1,0.1,2,0.25,3,0.33
2,2,0.1,4,0.25,6,0.33
3,3,0.1,8,0.25,12,0.33
4,4,0.1,16,0.25,24,0.33
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \foreach \hopp in {1,3,...,5}{
                \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma, header = false]{data.csv}{\mytableu}
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]{\number\numexpr\hopp+1\relax}}\of{\mytableu}
                \let\mydummy\pgfplotsretval
            \addplot table [
            col sep = comma, x=A, y index=\hopp
            ]{data.csv}
            node [
            pos={0.8}, sloped,anchor=center, fill = white,
            ] 
            {\mydummy};
        }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]